# Coping file from inputstream to outputstream results in bad copy

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload

I made an upload file servlet, summed up like this:

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
     FileItemStream item = iter.next();
     InputStream stream = item.openStream()
     File file = new File(path +"/"+ item.getFieldName));

     FileOutputStream fout= new FileOutputStream (file);
     BufferedOutputStream bout= new BufferedOutputStream (fout);
     BufferedInputStream bin= new BufferedInputStream(stream);
     byte buf[] = new byte[2048];
     while ((bin.read(buf)) != -1){
        bout.write(buf);
     }
     bout.close();
     bin.close();
}
```

I used streams so that the file isn't loaded in memory.

The files are being uploaded smoothly, but I cannot open the resulted file (error differs depending on file type). Also the size of the resulted file is larger then the one of the original.

I tried different types of stream readers and writers but couldn't get any closer, and I couldn't find a similar problem.
I ruled out encoding as I am receiving and writing bytes, so encoding doesn't matter, right?

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing all the content of buf array. This could be the problem for last read.

Change the `while` loop like this:

```
int n;
while ((n = bin.read(buf)) != -1)
{
    bout.write(buf, 0, n);
}
```